# How to edit Hibernate Search java Source Code, or maybe a workaround?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I am trying to add FullTextFilters to my FullTextQuery in hibernate and there is only the method `FullTextFilter.setParameter(String name, Object value)`

I am trying to make a flexible, generic function to add filters to the query based on the entity its searching for, some have one parameter, some have two for their filters, so I would like to add a method to `FullTextFilterImpl`; `setParameters(String[] names, String[] value)` where I can pass in the names of all the parameters and probably a multidimensional array of the values for each parameter to transform my current code of

```
If( "checking which entity it is"){
  fullTextQuery.enableFullTextFilter("FilterName").setParameter("firstFilter", "val1").setParameter("secondFilter", "val2");
}
else if("this entity's filter only has one parameter"){
     fullTextQuery.enableFullTextFilter("FilterName").setParameter("firstFilter", "val1");
}
```

I tried creating a subclass of FullTextFilterImpl and putting a `setParameters` function in it, but the way this code is set up I'm not sure how to utilize it as `FullTextQuery.enableFullTextFilter(filterName)` returns a `FullTextFilter` object and then you call the `setParameter()` on that object.  I'm not sure how I would get in the middle of that to do a `setParameters`

EDIT: I have downloaded the hibernate-search source code and added the following method to FullTextFilterImpl which I think will do what I want, but when I go to build it (even just the out-of-the-box project) I get all these checkstyle `Only one new line is allowed at the end of a file` errors.  Is there something I'm missing from the hibernate quick-build guide.

```
public FullTextFilter setParameters(Map<String, List<String>> params){
    for (String key : params.keySet()) {
        List<String> values = params.get(key);
        for(int i=0; i< values.size() ; i++){
            parameters.put(key, values.get(i));
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily pass a Map of attributes to your custom Filter, the signature is:

```
FullTextFilter setParameter(String name, Object value);
```

so you could do

```
filter.setParameter( "myMap", properties );
```

where properties is an hashmap.

About the compilation error message:

> Only one new line is allowed at the end of a file

is a message from checkstyle, it verifies code style is conforming to the Hibernate code style.
It's very simple to fix: there are multiple empty lines at the end of the source file, delete them. The error message should tell you what file needs to be polished.

Comment: That is true, I semi thought of that, but a filter might have more than one property and each property could have a list of values, so I thought it would be easier to do it where the parameters are passed in vs the actual filter that I made.  But I think I'll end up doing that.  As for the compile thing, I did try and delete the empty lines there but then it threw another error saying it was missing an empty line lol so I just removed that test altogether.

Answer (score 1):

if i correctly understand you question you need [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

here an example you could use :

```
public class FullTextFilter {

    String[] keys;
    Object[] objects;

    private FullTextFilter(String[] keys, Object[] objects) {
    }

    public static FullTextFilterBuilder builder(){
        return new FullTextFilterBuilder();
    }

    public static class FullTextFilterBuilder {

        private Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        public FullTextFilterBuilder setParameter(String key, Object value){
            parameters.put(key, value);
            return this;
        }

        public FullTextFilter build(){
            return new FullTextFilter(parameters.keySet().toArray(new String[0]), parameters.values().toArray(new Object[0]));
        }
    }

}
```

and then using it like this :

```
FullTextFilter filter = FullTextFilter.builder().setParameter("", new Object()).setParameter("", new Object()).build();
```

tell if that's what you are looking for.
if not i'll delete my answer

Comment: Sort of, except for two things, 1. I want to be able to use the same block of code for creating a filter whether or not it requires 1 or more `.setParameter`'s 2. Also, I'm not sure how hibernate is doing it but I don't think I can just work on a separate `Filter` object as the way it's doing it now the filter object is returned from `FullTextQuery.enableFullTextFilter` and the `.setParameter`s act upon it but the object itself doesn't get passed in anywhere or set to anything, it almost looks like it just gets thrown on the floor.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want this:

```
fullTextQuery.enableFullTextFilter("FilterName").setParameter("firstFilter", "val1").setParameter("secondFilter", "val2");
```

fullTextQuery{
name:"FilterName"
,parameters:["filter1":"value1", "filter2":"value2"]
}

```
static FullTextQuery enableFullTextFilter(String name){...}
FullTextQuery setParameter(String key, String value){
   parameters.put(key, value);
   return this;
}
```

assuming a parameters hashmap.

---

seeing as I was a little off base.. cant you do something like this?

```
setFilters (HashMap<String, String> filters) {
  FullTTextFilter fl = FullTextQuery.enableFullTextFilter("filtername");
  for (String key : filters.keySet()) {
    fl.setParameter(key, filters.get(key));
  }
}
```

Comment: Something like that might work, but I'm not sure how to actually edit the source code of Hibernate as its in a jar.

Comment: my fault for not reading **Hibernate** in there. Maybe we need what you want to achieve, there might be a different approach.